# Creating a command prompt environment that provides a dash and a blinking cursor

Tags: cmd

I am watching a tutorial about the command prompt
The author creates this

```
D:/CPPDEBUG>DEBUG
-_
```

The above code is an environment with a dash and a blinking cursor. 
I have no problem creating

D:/CPPDEBUG>DEBUG

But when I press return I get the message 'DEBUG' is not recognised as an external or internal commmand, operable program or batch file.

What should I do to recreate the environment that has the dash and blinking cursor?

Comment: install the software. `Debug` is an external utility, not a "standard" program.

Comment: What operating system?